# count files created from a month in php

Tags: php, file, date, count

I managed to count files in a folder with php.

```
count(scandir($snap_folder))
```

But now I would need to count only files created in the last 30 days and return the number.

this code returns always 0 even if I have files in the folder ?

```
 <?php
$snap_user = $_POST['snap_user'];
if (!file_exists($snap_user)){mkdir($snap_user, 0755, true);};
$snap_folder = $snap_user . '/';

$files = scandir($snap_folder);

$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($file)) >= $limit && !in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $count
?>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: Are you doing any validating/sanitizing of the POSTed data? You don't need that `;` after `}`. Did you call `var_export($files);` before the loop?  Might you entertain the idea of `chdir()` and `glob()`? That would omit the `.` and `..` issue.  Please post more relevant details so that we can help and potentially reopen your question.

Comment: Also, I recommend processing the timestamp instead of a human-readable date.  Just be sure the stamp is set to midnight.  Are you getting any errors?  Have you echoed `$limit` or `filemtime()` in your loop?  `echo $count` wants a semicolon.

Comment: When you are making a new directory, there is no use checking/counting it.

Comment: Don't you want `!is_dir()`?

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa and thanx for your reply. Sorry but I'm a total newbee in php... here is the code I finally use thanx to jawbonewalk : <?php
$snap_user = $_POST['snap_user'];
if (!file_exists($snap_user)){mkdir($snap_user, 0755, true);};
$snap_folder = $snap_user . '/';
$files = scandir($snap_folder);      
$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filename = $snap_folder . $file;
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($filename)) >= $limit) {
        $count++;
  $count2 = $count -2;
    }
}
echo $count2;
?>

Answer (score 2):

The code should look something like that

```
$files = scandir('folder/');

$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
  if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($file)) >= $limit) {
    $count++;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
$files = scandir('folder/');      
$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($file)) >= $limit && !in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
$folder = './folder/';
$files = scandir($folder);      
$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filename = $folder . $file;
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($filename)) >= $limit && !in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Thx, I tried but it always returns 2 ?
<?php
$snap_user = $_POST['snap_user'];
if (!file_exists($snap_user)){mkdir($snap_user, 0755, true);};
$snap_folder = $snap_user . '/';

$files = scandir($snap_folder);

$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
  if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($file)) >= $limit) {
    $count++;
  }
}

echo $count
?>

Comment: That's because the script is counting . and .. you can add some code to remove them from count

Comment: Thx for helping me jawbonewalk, and sorry if i'm being stupid, but I still can't make it work, I have 5 files in the folders created today and it stills retunrs 0 ? here is the complete code : <?php
$snap_user = $_POST['snap_user'];
if (!file_exists($snap_user)){mkdir($snap_user, 0755, true);};
$snap_folder = $snap_user . '/';
$files = scandir($snap_folder);
$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($file)) >= $limit && !in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
        $count++;
    }
}
echo $count
?>

Comment: thanx ! the !in_array was not working so I finally done this : <?php
$snap_user = $_POST['snap_user'];
if (!file_exists($snap_user)){mkdir($snap_user, 0755, true);};
$snap_folder = $snap_user . '/';
$files = scandir($snap_folder);      
$limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
$count = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filename = $snap_folder . $file;
    if (date ("Y-m-d", filemtime($filename)) >= $limit) {
        $count++;
  $count2 = $count -2;
    }
}
echo $count2;
?>
Pretty ugly but it works ;) THX AGAIN !!!

Comment: I edited the code in EDIT2, should work now and remove . and .. from count